# switching players when countdown hits 0 with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my code is all about changing players/streams

here's my plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/nV10XXQI2QStydCIYuyQ?p=preview some how it doesn't work currectly on plnkr but here's my page witth same code http://tgo-tv.com/test/page1.php

how ever, as you see when you go to the page , first countdown starts from 10 seconds then it will display player. i want to make it like, even when i clicked on any video buttons like Video 1 or Video 2 etc.. it should start countdown for new player

here's my js code hope ou understand

```
<script>
  function startChecking() { 
secondsleft -= 1e3, document.querySelector(".load_video").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds", 0 == secondsleft && (clearInterval(interval), $(".reloadframe").show(), document.querySelector(".load_video").style.display = "none", document.querySelector(".frame_src").style.display = "", document.querySelector(".frame_src").src = document.querySelector(".frame_src").getAttribute("data-src"), $("#btn_click_to_play").hide()) 
}

function startschedule() { 
document.querySelector(".frame_src").src = "about:blank"; 
clearInterval(interval), secondsleft = threshold, document.querySelector(".load_video").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds", interval = setInterval(function() { 
startChecking() 
}, 1e3) 
}

function resetTimer() {
    startschedule()
}
var timeout, interval, threshold = 1e4,
    secondsleft = threshold;
window.onload = function() {
    startschedule()
};

</script>
```